AVFoundation: Decode video frames in lower resolution before processing
We are processing videos with Core Image filters in our apps, using an AVMutableVideoComposition (for playback/preview and export).
For older devices, we want to limit the resolution at which the video frames are processed for performance and memory reasons. Ideally, we would tell AVFoundation to give us video frames with a defined maximum size into our composition. We thought setting the renderSize property of the composition to the desired size would do that.
However, this only changes the size of output frames, not the size of the source frames that come into the composition's handler block. For example:
let composition = AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in
    let input = request.sourceImage // <- this still has the video's original size
    // ...
})
composition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1280, heigth: 720) // for example

So if the user selects a 4K video, our filter chain gets 4K input frames. Sure, we can scale them down inside our pipeline, but this costs resources and especially a lot of memory. It would be way better if AVFoundation could decode the video frames in the desired size already before passing it into the composition handler.
Is there a way to tell AVFoundation to load smaller video frames?

The AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest property sourceImage header has a comment that says "Unlike AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest, renderContext.renderTransform is already applied to the source image.", so if you can get a / the renderContext you should be able to shrink the image.

Yes, the context is available inside the handler block. But it just gives me the information about the size the frames should have after rendering. The video frames that come into the composition are still full-sized, and I have to scale them myself. I'd rather have AVFoundation scale them for me during decoding.

Alternatively you can pass in a kCVPixelBufferWidthKey and kCVPixelBufferHeightKey to your pixel buffer properties for whatever your decode path is (as options for say a track reader output). This will vend smaller pixel buffers, but i dont think it will do the most efficient thing all the time, but should work everywhere by introducing a VImage pass inside the video toolbox decompression session.

You can use VideoToolbox keys for some video codecs which support progressive decode.
See kVTDecompressionPropertyKey_ReducedResolutionDecode and the keys kVTDecompressionResolutionKey_Width and kVTDecompressionResolutionKey_Height
alternatively you can use
kVTDecompressionPropertyKey_ReducedCoefficientDecode
you may need to poke the codec with kVTDecompressionPropertyKey_PixelFormatsWithReducedResolutionSupport to ensure the pixel format you are requesting for decode is viable
Ive not personally handled this, but i believe that ProRes and HEVC support this feature (HEVC if encoded correctly) and ProRes for all variants.
Im not sure about other codecs like H.264
you can pass Video Toolbox keys to your a AVAssetReaderOutput or AVPlayerItemOutput using the AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey as described in the AVVideoSettings header

Thanks for the reply! How do I "poke the codec" for the pixel buffer format?

sorry missed this - create a video decode session with the codec in question and request the value for the key kVTDecompressionPropertyKey_PixelFormatsWithReducedResolutionSupport
